# K2 manual rating

Tags: php, joomla, rating, k2

Hope you can help me here. My problem is following: I would like to set and dynamicaly change [K2](http://extensions.joomla.org/extension/k2) item rate by my self while creating/modifying it. I'm using sorting "Highest Rated" and found out that it works like

```
$query .= ", (r.rating_sum/r.rating_count) AS rating";
```

so I suppose that i need to change parameter rating_sum and set rating_count to 1 permanently. So the question is next: How can I realize it? Whould be great to pick value from  from 1 to 5.

I added [printscreen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hWtOx.jpg) of that what I want

In code I wrote

```html
<td class="k2Center center"> 
         
<select id="ratenews">
                <option value="0.0">0</option>
    <option value="0.5">1</option>
    <option value="1.0">2</option>
    <option value="1.5">3</option>
    <option value="2.0">4</option>
    <option value="2.5">5</option>
    <option value="3.0">6</option>
    <option value="3.5">7</option>
    <option value="4.0">8</option>
    <option value="4.5">9</option>
    <option value="5.0">10</option>
</select>
</td>
```

And now I would like to change value of $rating_sum according to value selected and to set it as the rate of article. I found something in post here [K2_content module rating](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12134185/k2-content-module-rating) but dont know how to use it. Please help!

Comment: Can you please give a (meaningful) set of sample data and the expected result for that data? (meaning: At least I didn't get what you're trying to achieve.)

Comment: The main aim is to sort articles according to its rate. But the rate of article should be defined not by users, but by myself. For example I'm creating a new article now and at this moment its rate should be 5/5. And it should be at the top of the sorting list. But in hour a would like to change it's rate to 4/5. So I would like to have such option to change item rate in administration part of K2